# Serializing a collection of MongoDB ObjectIds to string

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I am using `spring-data-mongodb` and I can do

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
private ObjectId userId;
```

in my models to serialize an `ObjectId` to string. The problem is when I have a list of ObjectIds. In that case `ToStringSerializer` does not work.

What should I do for correctly serializing the following?

`private Set<String> queryIds;`

Comment: for collection/ array or values of map you can use ```contentUsing``` instead of ```using``` in ```JsonSerialize```

Comment: @JEY fantastic thank you!